# How do I draw parallel lines that are at an angle relative to the coordinate system?

Tags: tikz-pgf

How do I draw parallel lines that are at an angle relative to the coordinate system? In the picture below you can see three parallel lines (purple and dotted). It's been done but more or less brute force, but I am sure that it is possible to copy, or repeat the lines just by using a local coordinate system. I can't find the way and would be grateful for any help.

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,fit}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections,positioning,calc}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

    % grid and axes
    \draw[very thin,color=gray] (-0.1,-0.1) grid (7,7);    
    \draw[->,name path=xaxis] (-0.2,0) -- (8,0) node[right] {$x_{11}$};
    \draw[->,name path=yaxis] (0,-0.2) -- (0,8) node[above] {$x_{12}$};

    % lines  
    \draw[color=red,ultra thick,name path=line1,domain=-0.5:5.5] plot (2,\x) node[above right] {$x_{11} = 2$};
    \draw[color=blue,ultra thick,name path=line2,domain=1.5:6.5] plot (\x,{6 -  \x}) node[below right] {$x_{11} + x_{12} = 6$};
    \draw[color=green!90!black,ultra thick,name path=line3,domain=-0.5:7.5] plot (\x,3) node[above right] {$x_{12} = 3$};
   
   
   % Parallel lines
    \draw[dotted,color=purple!90!red,ultra thick,name path=line4,domain=-.5:1.5] plot (3*\x,-2*\x) node[above right] {};
    \draw[dotted,color=purple!90!red,ultra thick,name path=line5,domain=-.4:1.6] plot (1+3*\x,2-2*\x) node[above right] {};
    \draw[dotted,color=purple!90!red,ultra thick,name path=line6,domain=-.7:1.3] plot (3+3*\x,3-2*\x) node[above right] {};

    % calculate intersection points
    \node[name intersections={of=line1 and line3}] (a) at (intersection-1) {};
    \node[name intersections={of=line2 and line3}] (b) at (intersection-1) {};
    \node[name intersections={of=line1 and xaxis}] (d) at (intersection-1) {};
    \node[name intersections={of=line2 and xaxis}] (c) at (intersection-1) {};

    % polytope    
    \filldraw[thick,fill=green!80!black,fill opacity=0.4] (a.center) -- (b.center) -- (c.center) -- (d.center)  -- cycle;


     % vectors
    \draw[color=red,ultra thick,->] (2,2) -- (2.7,2) node[above] {$(1,0)$};
    \draw[color=blue,ultra thick,->] (4.5,1.5) -- (5.5,2.5) node[right] {$(1,1)$};
    \draw[color=green!90!black,ultra thick,->] (5,3) -- (5,4.2) node[above] {$(0,1)$};
    \draw[ultra thick,color=purple!90!red,->] (0,0) -- (-1,-1.5) node[below] {$(-2,-3)$};
    
    \draw[dashed, thick,color=purple!90!red,<->] (2.33,-3) -- (3.67,-1) node[above] {$min$};
    \path (2.33,-3) node [text=purple!90!red,below] {max};


\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: It is very simple to draw rotated lines. `\draw[rotate=-30] (0,0) edge ++ (2,0)  (0,1) edge ++ (2,0);`, which can be combined with `foreach` etc. The question is whether one needs all the details of your code to phrase the question. Most of the ingredients do not seem to have an obvious relation to the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image: parallel lines]

Just chose whatever starting point and let's go with a `foreach` command. I let you adapt this to your own purpose and will.

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,fit}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections,positioning,calc}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

    % grid and axes
    \draw[very thin,color=gray] (-0.1,-0.1) grid (7,7);    
    \draw[->,name path=xaxis] (-0.2,0) -- (8,0) node[right] {$x_{11}$};
    \draw[->,name path=yaxis] (0,-0.2) -- (0,8) node[above] {$x_{12}$};

    % lines  
    \draw[color=red,ultra thick,name path=line1,domain=-0.5:5.5] plot (2,\x) node[above right] {$x_{11} = 2$};
    \draw[color=blue,ultra thick,name path=line2,domain=1.5:6.5] plot (\x,{6 -  \x}) node[below right] {$x_{11} + x_{12} = 6$};
    \draw[color=green!90!black,ultra thick,name path=line3,domain=-0.5:7.5] plot (\x,3) node[above right] {$x_{12} = 3$};
   
   
   % Parallel lines
%    \draw[dotted,color=purple!90!red,ultra thick,name path=line4,domain=-.5:1.5] plot (3*\x,-2*\x) node[above right] {};
%    \draw[dotted,color=purple!90!red,ultra thick,name path=line5,domain=-.4:1.6] plot (1+3*\x,2-2*\x) node[above right] {};
%    \draw[dotted,color=purple!90!red,ultra thick,name path=line6,domain=-.7:1.3] plot (3+3*\x,3-2*\x) node[above right] {};
    
    % New parallel lines    
    \foreach \i in {1,...,5}
        \draw [dashed,cap=round,thick,purple] ($(-2,1)+(60:\i)$) --++ (-30:8);
        
        
    % calculate intersection points
    \node[name intersections={of=line1 and line3}] (a) at (intersection-1) {};
    \node[name intersections={of=line2 and line3}] (b) at (intersection-1) {};
    \node[name intersections={of=line1 and xaxis}] (d) at (intersection-1) {};
    \node[name intersections={of=line2 and xaxis}] (c) at (intersection-1) {};

    % polytope    
    \filldraw[thick,fill=green!80!black,fill opacity=0.4] (a.center) -- (b.center) -- (c.center) -- (d.center)  -- cycle;


     % vectors
    \draw[color=red,ultra thick,->] (2,2) -- (2.7,2) node[above] {$(1,0)$};
    \draw[color=blue,ultra thick,->] (4.5,1.5) -- (5.5,2.5) node[right] {$(1,1)$};
    \draw[color=green!90!black,ultra thick,->] (5,3) -- (5,4.2) node[above] {$(0,1)$};
    \draw[ultra thick,color=purple!90!red,->] (0,0) -- (-1,-1.5) node[below] {$(-2,-3)$};
    
%    \draw[dashed, thick,color=purple!90!red,<->] (2.33,-3) -- (3.67,-1) node[above] {$min$};
%    \path (2.33,-3) node [text=purple!90!red,below] {max};


\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! This was just what I need!

Answer (score 3):

Using the [`tzplot`](https://ctan.org/pkg/tzplot) package:

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
    
\usepackage{tzplot}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[ultra thick,>=to]
% grid and axes (same as in question)
\tzhelplines(-.1,-.1)(7,7)
\tzaxes[thin](-.2,-.2)(8,8){$x_{11}$}{$x_{12}$}
\tzline[draw=none]"xaxis"(0,0)(8,0)
% lines (same as in question)
\tzvfnat[red]"line1"{2}[-.5:5.5]{$x_{11}=2$}[ar]
\tzfn[blue]"line2"{6-\x}[1.5:6.5]{$x_{11}+x_{12}=6$}[br]
\tzhfnat[green]"line3"{3}[-.5:7.6]{$x_{12}=3$}[ar]
% intersections (same as in question)
\tzXpoint{line1}{line3}(a)
\tzXpoint{line2}{line3}(b)
\tzXpoint{line1}{xaxis}(d)
\tzXpoint{line2}{xaxis}(c)
% polytope (same as in question)
\tzpolygon*[fill=green,thick](a)(b)(c)(d);
% vectors (same as in question)
\tzline[red,->](2,2)(2.7,2){$(1,0)$}[a]
\tzline[blue,->](4.5,1.5)(5.5,2.5){$(1,1)$}[r]
\tzline[green,->](5,3)(5,4.2){$(0,1)$}[a]
\tzline[purple,->](0,0)(-1,-1.5){$(-2,-3)$}[b]
\tzline[purple,dashed,thick,<->](2.33,-3){$max$}[at start,b](3.67,-1){$min$}[a]
% dotted line
\tzLFn[purple,dotted](0,0){-2/3}[-1.5:4.5]
% <shift> lines (copy from dotted line)
\tzLFn[purple,dotted]<1,2>(0,0){-2/3}[-1.2:4.7]
\tzLFn[purple,dotted]<3,3>(0,0){-2/3}[-2.1:3.9]
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: `tzplot`  = PSTricks-like TikZ.

Comment: @TheCodeMocker That is intended as mentioned at the very beginning of the document.

Comment: Oh. I have not read it yet.